# Prove or find a counter example to the claim that for all sets A,B,C if A ∩ B = B ∩ C = A ∩ C = Ø then A∩B∩C ≠ Ø

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is a homework question of mine that Ive answered and I'd really like some feedback on my solution.

> Prove or find a counter example to the claim that for all sets $A,B,C$, $$\text{if  }A\cap B=B\cap C=A\cap C=\emptyset \text{ then } A\cap B\cap C\neq \emptyset$$.

Since I can only either prove it is true, OR find a counter example I have gone with the latter because I think this statement is not true.
My counter example is as follows:

Let $A = \{1,2,3 \}$ , $B = \{4,5,6 \}$ and $C = \{7,8,9 \}$.
It is then clear that $A ∩ B =  B ∩ C =  A ∩ C = \emptyset$ .

If we let $x ∈ A\cap B\cap C$ then $x$ must be in **$A$ and $B$ and $C$**. Since this cannot be possible because there are no common elements then this implies that $A∩B∩C$ has to be equal to a null set i.e $A∩B∩C = \emptyset$ and thereby showing that (at least for this scenario) if $A \cap  B =  B \cap  C =  A \cap  C = \emptyset$ then $A\cap B\cap C = \emptyset$.

Is this okay? Any feedback will be greatly appreciated thank you!

Comment: It is good. You could have made the typing easier by letting $A=B=C=\emptyset$.

Comment: I'm skeptical that the problem is correctly stated.  Already $A\cap B = \emptyset$ implies the conclusion $A\cap B \cap C = \emptyset$.  This is an illustration of "beware if the problem seems too easy."

Answer (score 6):

Is *always* false: $A\cap B\cap C\subset A\cap B$, so
$$A\cap B=\emptyset\implies A\cap B\cap C=\emptyset.$$

Answer (score 4):

It's clearly false. If $$x\in A\cap B\cap C$$ then $$x\in A\cap B=\emptyset$$ (and the other two empty sets, for that matter), so the three hypotheses in fact imply that $$A\cap B\cap C=\emptyset$$

And in general, if $$S=\emptyset$$ then $$S\cap X_1\cap X_2 \dots \cap X_n=\emptyset$$ as well.

Comment: It's clearly... **true**?  I think you are proving his result

Answer (score 1):

$$A=B=C=\emptyset$$ is a counterexample. Or $A=\{1\}, B=\{2\}$, $C=\{3\}$. The precedent holds, but the antecedent does not ($A\cap B\cap C\neq \emptyset$ is NOT true).